# Hit Testing ... is it possible to test items in a listbox or other items control

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, listitem, hittest

I'm trying to hit test items within a listbox but to no avail.  Is it possible?  The VisualTreeHelper shows the x,y coordinates returning 0,0 for each and every item within which would seem to rule hit testing out.  Does anyone know of a solution or workaround?

Comment: Please show us the code.

Answer (score 2):

What have you tried? Have you tried the [`UIElement.InputHitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.inputhittest.aspx) method? The [`VisualTreeHelper.HitTest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) method? Have you read through [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx)?

Based on your question I guess you're calling [`VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getoffset.aspx)? If so, the offset is relative to the parent, which may very well be 0,0.

You need to give us more information with which to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hti = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hti==-1)
    {
        //user didn't click on an item
    }
    else
    {
        //user clicked on an item
        if (hti==listBoxFolder.SelectedIndex)
        {
            //user clicked on the item that was already selected
        }
        else
        {
            //user clicked on an item that was not already selected
        }
    }
}
```

This assumes that `listbox1.SelectionMode` is set to `SelectionMode.One` (which is the default setting).